# resume: Present Perfect or Past Perfect?

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, past-perfect

I'm creating my resume, and I have to write about my education.

from 2007 until 2012 - I was a student (I'm not any more). Now I have to write that in sentence that has meaning.

**1.  I had been studying economics from 2007 until 2012.**

**2.  I have been studying economics from 2007 until 2012.**

Also, I want to stress this, that's why I'd like to use 'Continuous', but which one?

Comment: @OP, You indicated that you studied FROM 2007 UNTIL 2012. I believe it should be in the simple past tense because 2012 is already over. (i.e., STUDIED Economics from 2007 until/to 2012) unless you are taking up further studies?

Comment: You can use the simple past as shin suggested, or a past perfect: *I **have studied** economics from 2007 until 2012.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had been studying economics from 2007 to 2009.

I have been studying economics from 2007 to 2009.

If the OP wants to convey the message that he completed his study, I think he should use the past simple as follows:

I studied economics from 2007 to 2009.

You can use the past perfect and the past perfect continuous to emphasize the action that happened earlier to another action in the past.  The use of the past perfect continuous in this sentence tells us how you had spent the period 2007-2009, but it doesn't necessarily mean that you had completed your study.

As for the second sentence, it's not correct because it conveys the sense that you are still studying right at the time of speaking; your study isn't over yet.